# Sharing an array between two structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

A similar question has been asked before, but I have a few more in-depth questions about it.

Suppose I have the struct

```
struct thread {
    pagetable* pt;
    vnode* fdtable[64];
};
```

I have an existing instance of that struct, and a brand new instance called `p`. I want the `fdtable` element of `p` to point to the same `fdtable` array as the old struct, such that a change to the array in one struct will be reflected in the array of the other struct. However, when I do `p->fdtable = this->fdtable;` I get the error message `invalid array assignment`. If I try to get creative with casting, I get the error message `incompatible types in assignment of 'vnode**' to 'vnode* [64]'`

No matter what I try, the compiler is really adamant in preventing what I am trying to do. After doing some research online, it appears that what I am trying to do is impossible.

My question has several parts:

1. Why can I easily share other data types by simply assigning pointers `p->pt = this->pt;` but I can't for arrays? What was the reasoning for the design decision behind this? Since arrays can't change in size, why are they treated differently?
2. What is the easiest way to accomplish a shared array between structs? Right now my plan is to create a new type of struct that contains all of the shared information, and then simply make both structs point to this shared one. However, I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: 1. Because C++ does not work this way. Arrays don't really exist in C++. They are a figment of everyone's imagination. They're just a Jedi mind-trick. 2. This is what a pointer is for. Use a pointer with a complete, thorough understanding on the proper usage and scoping of objects in C++.

Comment: If you want both structs to point to an array (possibly the same), they should probably have a field which points to an array.

Comment: Also, is this question about c or c++? You've tagged it with both, but they are different languages.

Comment: you can use std::shared_ptr if you really are coding in c++

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why can I easily ... by simply assigning pointers

Because pointers are assignable.

> but I can't for arrays?

Because arrays are not assignable.

> Why can I easily share ... by simply assigning pointers

Because pointers are a form of indirection.

> but I can't for arrays?

Because arrays are not a form of indirection.

> why are they treated differently?

Pointers are simply special in how they achieve sharing of data through indirection. Okay, there is another form of indirection too (references), so pointers aren't quite unique in this regard.

> What was the reasoning for the design decision behind this?

Implicit indirection without explicit distinction of value types and references/pointers is simply impossible in a language that has explicit memory management rather than garbage collection. And garbage collection is considered undesirable due to its runtime overhead. Indirection itself has some overhead itself too.

So in short: Speed.

---

> 2. What is the easiest way to accomplish a shared array between structs?

That can be achieved through indirection: Instead of storing the array within the object, store pointer to the array instead. Multiple instances can then point to the same array.

Note however that it will be tricky to make sure that the lifetime of the pointed array is longer than the lifetime of the pointers. The easiest - although not necessarily optimal - way to solve this problem is to use shared ownership of the array through the use of a shared pointer.

> If I try to get creative with casting, I get the error message

Sounds like you dodged a bullet there. Thank the type system for saving your program.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you may have heard, arrays in C++ are not pointers.  An array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, but it is not itself a pointer.

To get an idea of why this doesn't work, first think about what a `thread` object looks like in memory.  It will be laid out something like this:

```
                  pagetable
                  +-------+
thread         +->+       |
+------------+ |  +-------+
| pt         +-+  vnode
+------------+    +-------+
| fdtable[0] +--->+       |
+------------+    +-------+
| fdtable[1] +-+  vnode
+------------+ |  +-------+
|            | +->+       |
| ...        |    +-------+
|            |    vnode
+------------+    +-------+
| fdtable[63]+--->+       |
+------------+    +-------+
```

So of course two `thread`s' `fdtable` subobjects can't *reference* the same array.  `fdtable` doesn't reference anything; `fdtable` *is* the array.

You could copy each element of one `thread`'s `fdtable` into another so that both `thread` objects reference the same `vnode` objects, but simple assignment won't work because of the (somewhat goofy) semantics of arrays in C++.  You would have to loop over the array and copy its elements individually:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    p->fdtable[i] = this->fdtable[i];
}
```

or use something like `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(this->fdtable, this->fdtable + 64, p->fdtable);
```